# Select with a string containing spaces using map_values not working as expected

Tags: json, jq

I have the following dataset :

```
{
  "data": {
    "system": [
      {
        "login": "vault keystore password",
        "password": "123456"
      },
      {
        "login": "vault keystore masked",
        "password": "MASK-789101112"
      },
      {
        "login": "vault salt",
        "password": "toto"
      },
      {
        "login": "vault iteration",
        "password": "10"
      },
      {
        "login": "keystore Alias",
        "password": "vault"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve in my shell the password when login is "vault keystore password".

The closest that I have found is :
`.data.system |map_values(select(.login == "vault keystore password"))[].password`
but it returns me not the expected output (I wanted `123456`):

```
"123456"
"toto"
"vault"
```

Could you please explain me the correct syntax ?

Comment: FYI - Your attempt is supposed to work. Its possibly a bug that it is not producing the expected output. The answers should possibly help explain the reason and not suggest alternate ways

Comment: Hello
Actually, I'm quite newbie with jq, and I was oriented to "map_values" by "the internet".
Your solution works, as well as the ones from pmf and dawg.
Now, I must confess that if "map_values" does not work as expected... I would say it's already much higher level than me ;)
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `map(select(..))` will solve your problem.

```
.data.system | map(select(.login == "vault keystore password"))[].password
```

By the official docs, using `map_values()` should also work. For some reason `jq` (jq-1.6) is misbehaving (possibly a bug) while using for this filter. The same filter works well with [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq).

Per [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L33), `map_values(..)` is just

```
def map_values(f): .[] |= f;
```

so essentially, your filter comes down to

```
.data.system[] |= select(.login == "vault keystore password")
```

which is producing 3 objects inside the list `system`, which is incorrect. On the other hand `gojq` handles it correctly. I would argue the whole issue is around the update assignment operator of `jq` (i.e. `|=`), which is known to have caused issues in the past. See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2051

`jq` has been stuck in a release limbo for a while now (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2305). So until the time a new release > 1.6 comes along, `gojq` would be an ideal replacement with much of the known issues fixed (those of jq).

---

On `gojq` version 0.12.12

```bash
echo '{"data":{"system":[{"login":"vault keystore password","password":"123456"},{"login":"vault keystore masked","password":"MASK-789101112"},{"login":"vault salt","password":"toto"},{"login":"vault iteration","password":"10"},{"login":"keystore Alias","password":"vault"}]}}' |
  gojq '.data.system | map_values(select(.login == "vault keystore password"))[].password'
```

produces

```
"123456"
```

Answer (score 2):

First iterare over the array, then select by criteria:

```bash
jq -r '.data.system[] | select(.login == "vault keystore password").password'

# or by importing a string from outside dynamically

jq -r --arg login "vault keystore password" '
  .data.system[] | select(.login == $login).password
'
```

```
123456
```

Comment: It answers the question, but doesn't answer why OP's attempt failed. Usually I admire your answers for crisp and clear context on the problem. But this time it doesn't

Comment: @Inian You're right, I've apparently overlooked the part explicitly asking for explanation on `map_values`, and unfortunately I also had to leave after posting my putatively complete answer. Thank you for taking up the slack, and amply getting to the bottom of the issue. I couldn't have done it better. @Burps Please consider accepting [Inian's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76235343/2158479).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
.data.system | .[] |select(.login=="vault keystore password").password
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NPtsX6_gJ7P)

Or as a jq command line:

```
jq -r '.data.system | .[] |select(.login=="vault keystore password").password'
```

Or you can use ruby:

```
ruby -r json -e 'JSON.parse($<.read)["data"]["system"].
    select{|h| h["login"]=="vault keystore password"}.
    each{|h| puts h["password"]}'
```

Either of those, given JSON on STDIN or as a file prints `123456` on STDOUT.

Comment: It is not about alternate ways. OP's attempt is supposed to work.